# How may times do I need to Intercept and Assault the Overseer?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I have found, shot down and survived destroying all the aliens that were in the Overseer.  I have done this seven or eight times.

My question is why does The Objectives always say:

- Build the Firestorm - Completed!
- Intercept the Overseer UFO
- Assault the Crashed Overseer UFO

I have intercepted and assaulted the Overseer UFO many times.

My research is complete.  I can't start any new research.
The Foundry is complete.  I have no available projects.
In the Situation Room 8/9 cities have one box filled 1 city has 2 boxes filled.

Again how may times do I need to Intercept and Assault the Overseer?

Answer (score 13):

You'll need to intercept and assault Overseer UFOs until you manage to clear the wreckage without destroying the [Ethereal Device](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Ethereal_Device_%28artifact%29) at the center of the UFO. Make sure you aren't blowing it up with explosives.

Comment: Did not even know you could do that.